# glmulti: excluding combinations of correlated predictor variables from candidate sets of glm models using glmulti

Tags: r

Is there a way to prevent correlated predictor variables above a certain r cut off to be included in the candidate glm models using glmulti?...maybe an argument/implementation that uses a correlation matrix/TRUE FALSE matrix that can be used to subset the variable combinations? This just illustrates how I would normally initiate glmulti and doesnt attemt to subset variables

```
global.model<-glm(y ~ x1+x2...+x28, data=all.data, family=binomial)
res <- glmulti(y ~ global.model, data=all.data,level=2,  crit="aicc")
```